# Handle Json Object and array of Json object dynamically

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am trying to use Retrofit.But in one scenario for same key I am getting Json object or array of Json object depending on request.
How can I handle such condition in retrofit?

Ex :

Request 1 :

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "batters": {
    "batter": [{
        "id": "1001",
        "type": "Regular"
    }, {
        "id": "1002",
        "type": "Chocolate"
    }]
}
```

}

Request 2 :

```
{
"id": "0001",
"type": "donut",
"batters": {
    "batter": {
        "id": "1001",
        "type": "Regular"
    }
}
```

}

In Request 1 for key "batter" return array of Json and for Request 2 it returns simple json object.

How can I handle this in Retrofit?

Comment: you can handle it manually by parsing the response instead of using gson converter

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Object" in gson model class and then while getting that object you can use "instance of" operator to determine its type after getting it.
So something like : 
    @SerializedName("batter")
    @Expose
    private Object batter;